# Jquery toggle issue, show 1 list on click but hide everything on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Soo, i have an issue which i know should be easy to solve... How nothing i have tried seems to work, i'm new in Javascript and even more of a newbie in Jquery so i hope someone can help me out.

http://jsfiddle.net/YNL9a/

Jquery code:

```
function hidedivs() {
    $("#content").children().hide();
};


$(document).ready(function() {
    hidedivs();
    $("#menu,#submenu").hide();
        $("h3").click(function(){
            $("#menu").toggle("slow");
            $("#submenu").hide("slow");
        });


    $("nav a").click(function(event){
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        hidedivs();
        $(url).toggle("slow");      
        $(url).children().hide();   
        $(url).find("h1, p, li, img").toggle(); 
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

And HTML code:

```
<h3> Marsel van Oosten Photography</h3>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <nav>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li> <a href=".work">Work</a></li>
            <li> <a href=".about">About</a></li>
            <li> <a href=".news">News</a></li>
            <li> <a href=".contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="submenu" class="work">
                <li> <a href=".people">People</a></li>
                <li> <a href=".objects">Objects</a></li>
                <li> <a href=".series">Series</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

            <section id="content">
                <div class="about">
                    <h1>About</h1>
                    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="news">
                    <h1>News</h1>
                    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
                </div>
                <div class="contact">
                    <h1>Contact</h1>
                    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="people">
                <h1>People</h1>
                <img src="images/people1.jpg" width="600" height="386">
                <img src="images/people2.jpg" width="600" height="400">
                </div>
                <div class="objects">
                <h1>Objects</h1>
                <img src="images/object1.jpg" width="600" height="400">
                <img src="images/object2.jpg" width="600" height="279">
                </div>
                <div class="series">
                <h1>Series</h1>
                <img src="images/series1.jpg" width="600" height="413">
                <img src="images/series2.jpg" width="600" height="416">
                </div>
            </section>
    </div>
```

Now my question is: when i click on the header/name, the menu drops down. (works)
Then when i click on Work, a submenu drops down (works).
When i click on links in the submenu it shows 2 picutures(works)
When i click on links in the menu it shows text ( works).
When i click on the h3/name again the menu/submenu hide again (works).
What i am trying to do is when the menu, submenu and photo's are showing. That they all hide when clicking on the h3/name and when i click on the name after they hide, that only the menu and nothing else shows up (to do the same story again :) )

Hope somoene can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your javascript, just add this line, as shown, inside the $("h3").click().

```
$("h3").click(function(){
    $("#menu").toggle("slow");
    $("#submenu").hide("slow");

    $("#content").children().hide("slow"); // Add this line
});
```

It will also hide the content/images, and you can repeat the whole process again. I think that's what you want, from your description. Please let me know, if that's now you want.

Comment: Thanks! works exactly as i wanted it to :) I just didn't add .children when i tried it myself :) anyway, thanks a lot!